# Does SWI-Prolog's `foreach/2` involve `freeze/2`?

Tags: foreach, prolog

On SWI Prolog's [foreach/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2), we read:

[image: Description of "foreach/2" from the SWI Prolog site]

The compatibility of the "aggregate" library which contains the `foreach/2` predicate [is stated to be](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)

> Quintus, SICStus 4. The forall/2 is a SWI-Prolog built-in and
>   term_variables/3 is a SWI-Prolog built-in with different semantics.

From the [SICStus Prolog documentation](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002daggregate.html#index-foreach_002f2-_0028aggregate_0029-1):

> `foreach(:Generator, :Goal)`
>
> for each proof of *Generator* in turn, we make a copy of *Goal* with
>   the appropriate substitution, then we execute these copies in
>   sequence. For example, `foreach(between(1,3,I), p(I))` is equivalent
>   to `p(1), p(2), p(3)`.
>
> Note that this is not the same as `forall/2`. For example,
>   `forall(between(1,3,I), p(I))` is equivalent to
>
> `\+ \+ p(1), \+ \+ p(2), \+ \+ p(3)`.
>
> The trick in `foreach/2` is to ensure that the variables of *Goal*
>   which do not occur in *Generator* are restored properly. (If there are
>   no such variables, you might as well use `forall/2`.)
>
> Like `forall/2`, this predicate does a failure-driven loop over the
>   *Generator*. Unlike `forall/2`, the *Goals* are executed as an ordinary conjunction, and may succeed in more than one way.

Taking the example on the SWI Prolog page, without the final unification:

```
?- foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y)).
dif(Y, 4),
dif(Y, 3),
dif(Y, 2),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 2),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 3),
dif(Y, 2),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 2),
dif(Y, 1),
dif(Y, 1).
```

I'm not sure why there is the output of all the `dif/2` instantiations and why there are repetitions of the same subgoal.

`foreach/2` should be decide that the conjunction of multiple `dif(Y,i)` is true, as unbound variable `Y` is evidently `dif` from an integer *i*.

But now:

```
?- foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y)), Y = 5.
Y = 5.
```

Ok, so no output except for `Y=5` because the goal succeeds. But what does the `Y=5` change? After `foreach/2`, Prolog has already been able to decide to that `foreach/2` is true (given the state of `Y` at the time `foreach/2` was run), so adding `Y=5` should not change anything.

But then:

```
?- foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y)), Y = 2.
false.
```

A later unification changes the outcome of `foreach/2`. How?

I thought that [`freeze/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=freeze/2) on `Y` might be involved to make the situation interesting, as in, we are really computing:

```
freeze(Y,foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y))).
```

This would more or less explain the printouts. For example:

```
?- freeze(Y,foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y))).
freeze(Y, foreach(between(1, 4, X), dif(X, Y))).

?- freeze(Y,foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y))), Y=5.
Y = 5.

?- freeze(Y,foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y))), Y=2.
false.
```

Is this what's going on?

Comment: Bonus question ... why is `forall(between(1,3,I), p(I))` equivalent to `\+ \+ p(1), \+ \+ p(2), \+ \+ p(3)`. What does the stacked "there is no evidence for (there is no evidence for p(1))" do?

Comment: `\+ \+ p(X)` is a common idiom to test that "p(X)" has a solution but without binding the variables appearing in it. In this particular case, because there is no variable appearing in "p(1)", the double negation would be unnecessary but not in the general case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "freezing" behaviour that you observe is due to dif/2, not foreach/2.

The predicate dif/2 ensures that its two arguments are not identical and will not become identical. So if the two arguments might become identical, then dif/2 is suspended until it can decide whether they are identical or not.

Comment: Thank you! So, the out output of the `dif(Y, 4),` lines are the suspended `dif/2` goals printed out by the toplevel. Because, I assumed wrongly that `dif(Y, 4),` is actually determined, it is not, and cannot be decided at that point. I confused with `dif` with `\==`